# Identify variable ordinalities

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sympy

Suppose I have a Pandas Series named `fruit` that looks like this:

```
mango, kiwi, pear, kiwi, pear, mango, mango.
```

and I know the price relationship between among these fruits is such that:

`mango = 1.2 * pear` and `kiwi = 0.8 * pear`

How do I convert the `fruit` column to a numeric such that:
`1.5, 1, 1.2, 1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.5`?

Not sure if I can do this using Python standard library or Pandas, or if I'd need to use SymPy. [Preference would be stdlib or Pandas].

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Following [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). When having:

```
s = pd.Series(['cat', 'dog', np.nan, 'rabbit'])
```

You simply call map function on your serie like:

```
s.map({'cat': 'kitten', 'dog': 'puppy'})
```

This returns a new pandas Serie.

Comment: I think the problem I am facing is identifying numeric values for each of the categorical variables, given their relationship with each other. In the example, assuming a kiwi costs $1, how to calculate that mango costs $1.5, etc. I could then construct a dict and map the numeric values to their corresponding categorical variable, as you showed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a self-consistent set of equalities you could do something like:

```
>>> eq=S('[mango = 1.2 * pear, kiwi = 0.8 * pear]'.replace('=','-'))
>>> v = solve(eq)
>>> S('Tuple(mango, kiwi, pear)').subs(v)
(1.2*pear, 0.8*pear, pear)
```

(In this case, not enough information was given to know the price of a pear, too. Note, too, that this will only work if the quantity on the rhs of the equation is not a sum of terms.)

I don't work with pandas so I am not sure how to advise regarding type conversion, e.g. converting from SymPy expressions back to items to go into your Series.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do:

```
s=pd.Series(['mango', 'kiwi', 'pear', 'kiwi', 'pear', 'mango', 'mango'],name='fruit')
```

---

```
pear=1
d={'mango':1.2 * pear, 'kiwi': 0.8 * pear,'pear':pear}
s.map(d).div(s.map(d).min()).round(1)
```

---

```
0    1.5
1    1.0
2    1.2
3    1.0
4    1.2
5    1.5
6    1.5
```